# Downgrade angularcli from @angular/cli@latest to angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24 getting error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I have upgraded `@angular/cli to 1.0.0`
as I am running my app in `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24` I want to downgrade cli to `1.0.0-beta.24`
when I try

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.24`

I am getting an error as

```
`npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.24
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/progton/.npm/_logs/2017-06-13T12_29_17_275Z-debug.log`
```

node -v : v6.11.0
npm : 5.0.3
os : ubuntu

I uninstalled `@angular/cli@lated` but I am not able to install the `@angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.24`

And what if the case I am running:

project 1 in angular 2 angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24

project 2 in angular 4 which is angular-cli@latest

please help here anyone please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers... :)

I got the solution for the problem 
for `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24` Peer dependencies are missing so the cli was not getting installed sometimes it was giving npm error as `package.json` is missing for `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24`

so I tried installing `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3`

then installed `sudo npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3`

next in project directory `npm install`

now if i do `ng serve` app is running fine and also for production if i do `ng build --prod --aot` it's working as expected

but if I do `ng -v` I am not getting the cli version I am getting error as `Error: Cannot find module 'command'`

but the overall app is working fine Thank you for help @Yakov Fain hope this may help

Answer (score 1):

Prior to beta 30, the name of the Angilar CLI package was not @angular/cli but angilar-cli. So try the following:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
npm cache clear
npm install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24 -g
```

Comment: I installed the same way but when I try to get version `ng -v` I am getting as `bash: /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory` even I installed dev dependencies also but no luck :(

Comment: I've updated my response. The -g was missing in the npm install command.